# Android Skype recorder

Tags: android, skype, skype4java

Hi i am trying to develop android app which will be able to record skype calls. Problem is lack of knowledge, could you give me a tips how to do it easy or where to start ?

**My idea is :**

- Create service which listens(i mean monitors) processes and when skype incoming/outgoing call is initiated, service launch's recorder - which starts recording immediately, both mic source of device and speaker source also, names recorded file with date and contact which has participated in conversation, and when the calls is done - it stops recording.

Comment: Based on this and your other questions, I would like to invite you to start with Android development. Get the SDK, install Eclipse, and get coding. Your questions show that you haven't done that yet, and you're not likely to get help here with just "out-there" ideas.

Comment: well, everything u've mentioned i did, i did research also on this topic, but the skype API's i've found are outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the community ratings suggest, you should try to give us code that isn't working and specifically ask for something that volunteers can fix.

Besides that point, here's what i do know from past experiences with Android and recording:

- for your app to record what is being displayed on the screen, you need access to the /dev0 graphics buffer, which is impossible unless you have your device rooted.
- Most android devices do not allow you to record voice data either. (not sure if you can when you root it, my guess is that you can, but would be still a hassle). There are ways to hack around this, i would look around other parts of stack overflow for this.

It depends on what your need for the application is. If you are trying to only get this app to work between a small number of people, then you may be able to download the Skype apk and reverse engineer it using Eclipse, a Java Decompiler and a dedexer (something like dex2jar).  Then root the device to get access to the video and sound buffer to record the data stream.

i DO NOT recommend this approach, and even attempting so might not guarantee that you can do it (especially if Skype uses proguard to obfuscate their code).

Comment: P.S. best of luck! by the way, you may ask your question on Stack Exchange or some other website that is more geared towards "approach" questions... stackoverflow seems to be almost exclusively coding based and almost every question has some code in it

Comment: Thanks a lot David again, well by this time app is made :D im new at android (just 2 days) and i made an app thanks to Stack's great community. I just needed to read more and then try different approaches...

Comment: Heh, sorry i couldn't be of more help :) glad to see you using the community!